# Read and write file atomically

Tags: ruby, atomic

I'd like to read and write a file atomically in Ruby between multiple independent Ruby processes (not threads).

- I found [`atomic_write`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/File/Atomic.html) from ActiveSupport. This writes to a temp file, then moves it over the original and sets all permissions. However, this does not prevent the file from being read while it is being written.
- I have not found any `atomic_read`. (Are file reads already atomic?)

Do I need to implement my own separate 'lock' file that I check for before reads and writes? Or is there a better mechanism already present in the file system for flagging a file as 'busy' that I could check before any read/write?

---

<sup>The motivation is dumb, but included here because you're going to ask about it.</sup>

<sup>I have a web application using [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) and served by [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) which (for its own reasons) uses a JSON file as a 'database'. Each request to the server reads the latest version of the file, makes any necessary changes, and writes out changes to the file.</sup>

<sup>This would be fine if I only had a single instance of the server running. However, I was thinking about having multiple copies of Thin running behind an Apache reverse proxy. These are discrete Ruby processes, and thus running truly in parallel.</sup>

<sup>Upon further reflection I realize that I really want to make the act of read-process-write atomic. At which point I realize that this basically forces me to process only one request at a time, and thus there's no reason to have multiple instances running. But the curiosity about atomic reads, and preventing reads during write, remains. Hence the question.</sup>

Comment: Checking and then acting (as with lock file) is prone to race conditions. You don't want to separate the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`File#flock`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-i-flock) in exclusive mode. Here's a little demo. Run this in two different terminal windows.

```
filename = 'test.txt'

File.open(filename, File::RDWR) do |file|
  file.flock(File::LOCK_EX)

  puts "content: #{file.read}"
  puts 'doing some heavy-lifting now'
  sleep(10)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. When is the lock released? When the file handle is closed? Also, the documentation says "not available on all platforms". Do you have any idea what platforms it is/is not available on?

Comment: I suppose. But you can unlock explicitly by calling `file.flock(File::LOCK_UN)`

Comment: As for the platform support: I *think* it's something that unixes would have. Features tend not to work on windows, but I did a similar thing on windows ~10 years ago. Not in ruby, though, but the OS had the capabilities back then. You should try :)

Comment: Watch out for filesystems too, especially shared filesystems like nfs

Comment: I'm going to accept this for now, as it looks like the right answer. The ambiguities around OS and file system limitations make me think that a better answer might exist. If you have one, post it, and perhaps I'll switch the acceptance.

Comment: Looking into possibly using this today, and I hear it's bad practice to utilize locks in *nix systems, at least exclusive ones, in case the process dies and you can no longer possibly access the file, until I'm guessing, you restart the system.  Instead, I should be making a temporary file and renaming it to achieve an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `transaction` and `open_and_lock_file` methods in "pstore.rb" (Ruby stdlib).

`YAML::Store` works fine for me. So when I need to read/write atomically I (ab)use it to store data as a `Hash`.